# Can't create and reference a keyvault secret in the same ARM template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

as part of a deployment I'm doing I want to deploy a Key vault into a resource group, create some secrets and then deploy a SQL server into another resource group using one of these secrets as the admin password. The following is a snippet of the resources I am using to do this:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
  "name": "[variables('KeyVaultName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": "true",
    "accessPolicies": "[variables('KeyVaultAccessPolicies')]",
    "tenantId": "[parameters('TenantId')]",
    "sku": {
      "name": "Standard",
      "family": "A"
    }
  }
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
  "name": "[concat(variables('KeyVaultName'), '/secretname')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
  "properties": {
    "value": "<a randomised value>"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('KeyVaultName'))]"
  ]
},
{
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
  "name": "deploy",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "resourceGroup": "<another resource group>",
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "<my linked template>",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "SQLServerAdminPasswordSecretName": {
        "value": "secretname"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', variables('KeyVaultName'), 'secretname')]"
  ]
}
```

My linked template is also has a deployment which looks a bit like the following:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
    "name": "sql-server-deployment",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
            "uri": "<another linked tempalate>",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "SQLServerName": {
                "value": "[variables('SQLServerName')]"
            },
            "SQLServerAdminPassword": {
                "reference": {
                    "keyVault": {
                        "id": "[resourceId(parameters('ParentResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('ParentKeyVaultName'))]"
                    },
                    "secretName": "[parameters('SQLServerAdminPasswordSecretName')]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This reference is currently killing my entire deployment saying:

> "The specified KeyVault '/subscriptions/[subscription
>   id]/resourceGroups/[parent resource
>   group]/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/[my keyvault]' could not be
>   found."

If I remove the Keyvault reference in my linked template the error goes away.

What is confusing to me is that the linked template deployment depends on the key vault secret, which in turn depends on the key vault, yet nothing is being deployed because the key vault reference is trying to be resolved before anything else.

Am I missing something obvious or is this a flaw in ARM templates?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter references are evaluated at "compile" time (i.e. validation), so the vault does need to exist when the template is validated.  You *might* be able to pull this off by nesting a few levels deep and using output references from the nested deployment.  You'd need to do something like this:

- Nest the vault setup and output the vaultId
- nested the SQL Server deployment into a "level 1" nesting
- in the parameters for the above bullet, reference the output in step 1
- nest another deployment with the parameter reference constructed from the vaultId in the "level 1" nesting

That said, I'm interested in why you'd want to do this... normally the vault reference is used to keep a secret out of plain text/json.  Since you're passing the secret value into the deployment at the top level, you already have the value.  There's no reason to reference it from the vault since you already have it...

Comment: why do you want to nest the vault deployment if you can just construct the vault id without referencing it (since you know the vault name)? you could just add a dependsOn and have a structure like this: `kv, kv secret, linked template using reference as an input to a parameter with dependsOn "kv secret"`. At least in my mind this sounds right

Comment: Using a deployment output as the key vault Id reference stops the value being evaluated until the key vault has been deployed, this works perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: reference always works after the deployed resource, i dont think it matters

Comment: using a deployment output reference as in input to a template deployment prevents pre-flight validation from being run on that deployment...

Comment: @bmoore-msft can you please help with my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037021/how-to-set-a-connection-string-for-web-app-in-arm-template-that-references-a-key